# Error handling in Swift non-optional-valued functions

Tags: string, swift, error-handling

Trying to get to grips with Swift programming, I wrote the following:

```
var s : String = "dog"
var i1 : String.Index = advance(s.startIndex, 2)
var t1 : String = s.substringToIndex(i1)
```

Executing this code in a playground, `t1` has the value `"do"`, as expected. However, if I try to construct an index that exceeds the string's length, this happens:

```
var s : String = "dog"
var i2 : String.Index = advance(s.startIndex, 4)
var t2 : String = s.substringToIndex(i2)
```

This time, the line `var i2 ...` shows the error

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0).

I read the Swift documentation, but the entry for `String.substringToIndex` reads in its entirety:

> `func substringToIndex(index: String.Index) -> String`
>   [Foundation]
>
> Returns a new string containing the characters of the String up to, but not including, the one at a given index.

The result is not optional, nor does the function possess an error parameter or return an empty string in case of faulty arguments.

I don't know how to prevent this by not creating an index in the first place, because `String` does not have a `length` or `count` property.
Since Swift does not have exception handling, how can programs recover from errors like this?

This is on OS X 10.10.2, Xcode 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in `advance(s.startIndex, 4)` as you cannot advance eyond the end index:

```
  1> var s = "dog"
s: String = "dog"

  2> var i1 = advance(s.startIndex, 4)
fatal error: can not increment endIndex
i1: String.Index = {
  _base = { /* ... */ }
  /* ... */
  }
Execution interrupted. Enter Swift code to recover and continue.
Enter LLDB commands to investigate (type :help for assistance.)
```

You avoid this by providing an end index as:

```
  3> var i1 = advance(s.startIndex, 4, s.endIndex)
i1: String.Index = {
  _base = { /* ... */ }
 /* ... */
}
```

and then:

```
  4> s.substringToIndex(i1)
$R0: String = "dog"
```

at least for Swift1.2, in Xcode6-Beta3.